# Sum of users votes using parameters ActiveRecord Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I simply want to display in index.html.erb under `<th>User Votes</th>` how many users have voted for a bboy?

This is in my controller :

```
@raters_count = Rate.select(:rater_id).where(rateable_id: 3, rateable_type: 'Bboy' ).distinct.count
```

This is my index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing bboys</h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Crew</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Foundation</th>
      <th>Originality</th>
      <th>Dynamics</th>
      <th>Execution</th>
      <th>Battle</th>
      <th>User Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @bboys.each do |bboy| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= bboy.name %></td>
        <td><%= bboy.crew %></td>
        <td><%= bboy.country %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "foundation" %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "originality" %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "dynamics" %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "execution" %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "battle" %></td>
        <td><%= @raters_count %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', bboy %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_bboy_path(bboy) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', bboy, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Bboy', new_bboy_path %>
```

This is in my table bboys:

```
- !ruby/object:Bboy
  attributes:
    id: 3
    name: taisuke
    crew: japan
    country: JAP
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:32:56.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:32:56.000000000 Z
    avatar_file_name: justdoit.jpeg
    avatar_content_type: image/jpeg
    avatar_file_size: 9297
    avatar_updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:32:55.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Bboy
  attributes:
    id: 4
    name: roxrite
    crew: us
    country: us
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:35:40.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:35:40.000000000 Z
    avatar_file_name: 
    avatar_content_type: 
    avatar_file_size: 
    avatar_updated_at: 
- !ruby/object:Bboy
  attributes:
    id: 5
    name: me
    crew: japan
    country: JAP
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:23.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:23.000000000 Z
    avatar_file_name: justdoit.png
    avatar_content_type: image/png
    avatar_file_size: 91715
    avatar_updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:22.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Bboy
  attributes:
    id: 6
    name: asd
    crew: asd
    country: asd
    created_at: 2014-03-04 13:24:41.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 13:24:41.000000000 Z
    avatar_file_name: images.jpeg
    avatar_content_type: image/jpeg
    avatar_file_size: 7928
    avatar_updated_at: 2014-03-04 13:24:40.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Bboy
  attributes:
    id: 8
    name: name
    crew: name
    country: name
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:39:20.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:39:20.000000000 Z
    avatar_file_name: 
    avatar_content_type: 
    avatar_file_size: 
    avatar_updated_at:
```

This is in my table rates:

```
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 11
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 12
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 13
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 14
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 15
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 16
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 17
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 18
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 19
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 25
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 26
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 27
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 28
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 29
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
```

Schema.rb:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140225090908) do

      create_table "bboys", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "crew"
        t.string   "country"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.string   "avatar_file_name"
        t.string   "avatar_content_type"
        t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
        t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
      end

      create_table "bonghis", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "email"
        t.integer  "age"
        t.text     "summary"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      create_table "rates", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "rater_id"
        t.integer  "rateable_id"
        t.string   "rateable_type"
        t.float    "stars",         null: false
        t.string   "dimension"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      add_index "rates", ["rateable_id", "rateable_type"], name: "index_rates_on_rateable_id_and_rateable_type", using: :btree
      add_index "rates", ["rater_id"], name: "index_rates_on_rater_id", using: :btree

      create_table "rating_caches", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "cacheable_id"
        t.string   "cacheable_type"
        t.float    "avg",            null: false
        t.integer  "qty",            null: false
        t.string   "dimension"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      add_index "rating_caches", ["cacheable_id", "cacheable_type"], name: "index_rating_caches_on_cacheable_id_and_cacheable_type", using: :btree

      create_table "users", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.string   "avatar_file_name"
        t.string   "avatar_content_type"
        t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
        t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
      end

      add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
      add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a scope in `Rate` model as below:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :raters_count, ->(rateable_id) { select(:rater_id).where(rateable_id: rateable_id, rateable_type: 'Bboy' ).distinct.count } 

end
```

**In the view, access it as below:**

```
  <td><%= Rate.raters_count(bboy.id) %></td>
```

instead of

```
   <td><%= @raters_count %></td>
```

Also, remove `@raters_count` from the Controller.

Comment: I added scope in model and also <td><%= Rate.raters_count(bboy.id) %></td> in view, but now getting NameError in Bboys#index "undefined local variable or method `rater_id' for #<Class:0x00000004ae1df8>"?

Comment: Can you share the schema of your models from `schema.rb` file.

Comment: Just noticed that there was a typo in the answer. I have updated it. Try with that.

Comment: Also how can I make view AJAX so number updates itself without refreshing whole page?

Comment: Argument passed to the scope was `->(rateable_id)` and I used `rater_id` by mistake instead of using `rateable_id`. So you were getting the error. "undefined local variable or method `rater_id' for #<Class:0x00000004ae1df8>"

Comment: Could u please have a look at my code on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840627/rails-activerecord-model-sorting-how ? Thank u!